# RPI raw write to usb device (printer upgrade)

Tags: raspbian, usb, printing

Is there a way to write directly to EP of USB printer connected to Raspberry Pi 3?

When I try to write to usb directly i get write error: Invalid argument:

```
echo 1 > /dev/bus/usb/001/004
-su: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

I see this was once possible. I need raw interface for upgrade of the printer :(

Any idea why this is failing?

Answer (score 1):

finally found out myself how.

To be able to write raw data to printer usb device (could be also for others not just printer) use the usblp module.

```
modprobe usblp
echo 1 > /deb/usb/lp0
```

Could be that you also need to setup appropriate UDEV rules...

Hope it helps...